# In French, how do you say "X is known as the mother/father of Y"?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

> X is known as the **mother**/**father** of psychoanalysis/etc.

In English, both "mother" and "father" can be used figuratively to refer to a renowned figure responsible for the creation of something historically important.

I wonder if in French you can use both « père » and « mère » in the same manner, depending on the gender of the person in question?

---

On another note: When ***something*** instead of ***someone*** is the origin/cause of something else, we usually use "mother" in English. Can only « mère » work in French in this case?

> e.g. Necessity is the **mother** of invention.

Comment: [Max Planck est considéré comme le père de la physique quantique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physique_quantique).

Comment: @Laure, tu as une tendance à toujours répondre en commentaire, pourquoi ne pas faire une réponse courte à la place ?

Comment: @Jylo quel est l'intérêt de faire une réponse quand il suffit de consulter un dictionnaire ? Si encore je trouvais quelque chose d'original à dire, mais là il n'y a que du copier coller à faire...

Comment: @Laure si la question est vraiment mauvaise, il est possible de la fermer, sinon l'intérêt est de tomber sur la question en cas de recherche au lieu de chercher dans "mother" sur un dictionnaire (c'est plus rapide). De la même manière que sur le site principal tu peux penser que "c'est dans la documentation" mais chercher dans la doc est plus long que tomber sur la question. ("How do I undo the last commits in Git?" est la deuxième question la plus upvoté de Stack et la réponse est dans la doc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Père et mère en français, comme dans beaucoup de langues, sont employés pour parler du lien de paternité, qu'il soit biologique ou intellectuel.

**Père**  [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/p%C3%A8re)  (I, A, 3, a, β)

> Celui qui est le créateur d'une œuvre, l'auteur d'une découverte, l'inventeur ou l'inspirateur d'une doctrine, d'un système, d'une technique, etc.

« Max Planck est considéré comme le père de la physique quantique. »

Quand la personne est féminin, « père » devient « **mère** » :
« Simone Veil, icône de la lutte pour le droit des femmes et mère de la loi sur le droit à l'avortement va reposer au Panthéon. »

**Emplois figurés**

[TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/p%C3%A8re)  (I, A, 3, b)

> b) [Désigne une chose] Ce dont est issu quelque chose; cause, source, principe.
>   [...] le travail, père des bonnes mœurs (Courier, *Pamphlets pol*.,Au réd. « Censeur », 1820)

Quand la chose dont on parle est de genre féminin, « père » devient « mère » :

> L'agriculture est sainte ; elle est la mère nourrice de l'homme (T. Gauthier, *Le roman de la Momie*, 1858)

Dictons :
 [L’oisiveté est la mère de tous les vices](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/l%E2%80%99oisivet%C3%A9_est_la_m%C3%A8re_de_tous_les_vices)
La nécessité est la mère de l'invention. (Platon)

Les emplois figurés de ces rapports filiaux s'étendent au fils et à la fille :

**Fille** [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/fille) (I, B, c)

> Chose qui résulte d'une autre, est engendrée par elle. Synon. conséquence, résultat.
>   [...] C'est une idée assez commune que révolution et guerre sont filles de pauvreté (Alain, *Propos*,1926, p. 675)

« L'orgueil est un père cruel, ses filles les plus féroces sont l'envie et la vaine gloire. »
Alfred Auguste Pilavoine ; *Pensées, mélanges et poésies* (1845)

**Fils** [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/fils) (I, B, d)

> d) Au fig. Œuvre par rapport à son créateur.
>    Il [Canova] a passé plusieurs années à retoucher ce tableau, fils
>     heureusement unique de sa vieillesse (Sand, *Lettres voy*.,1837, p.
>     32).

Et on peut décliner ces rapports au fil de son imagination littéraire :
« Le mensonge est le père de tous les vices et le grand-père de toutes les fortunes. » (Benoît Barvin, *Proverbes en coin*).*

*<sub>Trouvé [ici](http://tomdrake.eklablog.com/le-mensonge-est-le-pere-de-tous-les-vices-et-le-grand-pere-de-toutes-l-a114797490), aucune autre source, mais qu'importe !</sub>

Comment: J'ai pas d'exemple pour le moment, mais tu pourrais ajouter que dans les cas abstraits, le choix _père/mère_ ou _fille/fils_ va se faire en fonction du genre du mot. Je ne pense pas que ce soit évident pour des personnes dont la langue maternelle n'attribue pas des genres aux mots.

Comment: @Unfrancophone C'était effectivement la seule chose qui valait de rédiger une réponse mais je croyais que je disais ça dans « Quand la chose dont on parle a personne est de genre féminin, « père » devient « mère » ».  Mais si ce n'est pas clair je veux bien reformuler, une suggestion ?

Comment: je relis et je trouve ça clair.  Je ne vois plus ce qui me gênait.